# How to search an element in a sorted 2-D array with order (n)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

if we have a sorted `array`:

```
12 13 14 17

17 19 21 28

21 56 68 190

67 87 92 900
```

and we have keys `21` and `62`. And we have to determine whether these keys are present in `array`. It is easy to do with `n^2`(n-square) order using 2 loops. But how to do it with order `n`.

Comment: Why is this tagged Java and C++11? Pick a language

Comment: For sorted arrays, you can determine presence in O(log n) time using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: Updated my solution for the `O(n)` case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that every row and every column of your array is ordered.
Consider the last element in the first row.

```
Row = 0
Col = N - 1

if Value = A[Row, Col] then 
    element is found
else
    if Value < A[Row, Col] then Value cannot be in this column, and we have to move left
        Col = Col - 1
    else
        if Value > A[Row, Col] then Value cannot be in this row, and we have to move down
              Row = Row + 1

Repeat steps until Value is found or border is reached.
```

We always do moves only to left and down, so complexity is at most (N + N) steps = O(N)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done... but is not really efficient:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array2d.length * array2d[0].length ; i++) {
      // i % array2d.length is the row
      // i / array2d.length    is the col
      if (array2d[i % array2d.length][i / array2d.length] == // your condition
}
```

Comment: using i<arr.length*arr.length[0] will be n^2 order

Comment: i need the search to be of order n.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve `O(log(n))` using [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Assume that you have the array **`a[1..N][1..N]`**, and you want to search the **`row`** and **`col`** for the value **`R`**. The pseudocode is:

```
lower_row <- 0
upper_row <- N
while (lower_row < upper_row):
    mid_row <- (lower_row + upper_row) / 2
    if (R >= a[mid_row+1][1])
        lower_row = mid_row+1
    else if (R <= a[mid_row][N])
        upper_row = mid_row

# now lower_row = upper_row = row
row <- lower_row

left_col <- 0
right_col <- N
while (left_col < right_col):
    mid_col <- (left_col + right_col) / 2
    if (R > a[row][mid_col])
        left_col = mid_col+1
    else if (R <= a[row][mid_col]
        right_col = mid_col

# now left_col = right_col = col
col <- left_col

return row, col
```

Now **`row`** and **`col`** is the coordinate of your value in array.

**Update:**
Seems like you just need to do it with the complexity `O(N)`, so it is very simple. Pseudocode:

```
row <- 1;
for i from 1 to N:
    if (a[i][1] < R and R < a[i][N])
        row = i

for j from 1 to N:
    if (a[row][j] = R)
        col = j

return row, col
```